# not able to get the id of the word from sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

I am getting the word from the text view and passing to DB to get its id, i am able to get the word but not able to get the id. 
please look at my code and tell me what is the mistake and help me correct it

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView txtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rightanswer);
        //Log.d("word " + txtView.getText(), "word");
        String word = txtView.getText().toString().trim();
        String words[] = new String[3];
        words = word.split(":");
        String selectedword = words[1].toLowerCase().trim();
        Log.d("Word", "|" + selectedword + "|");
        getWordId(selectedword);
    }
};

private int getWordId(String word) {
    // String selection = "Word=" + word;
    int id = -1;
    String query = "Select wordId from Words WHERE Word ='"+word+"'";
    //Log.d("Query ::" + query + "::", "Query");
    Cursor c = executeQuery(query);
    Log.d("Row Count", "" + c.getCount());
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("wordId"));
            Log.d("Id is:", "" + id);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Word.class);
            intent.putExtra("wordid", id);
            intent.putExtra("page", "QuizResult");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return id;
}
```

i get the row id as 0. please help me

Comment: please post the `query` & `executeQuery`

Comment: String query = "Select wordId from Words WHERE Word ='"+word+"'";
this is the query i am using to get the id of the word.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a requirement for Sqlite but there is a semicolon missing at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

To get the row number from the database you should be getting the unique key (_id). Is wordId your unique key in the database? I althought thought it was important to android to name the column _id for whatever reason.

Comment: wordId is the column name of the ids

Comment: It also doesn't appear as if your actually executing the sql. Try changing the column name to _id and executing using something like: database.execSQL(query); I'm assuming you have declared your database and opened the connection etc etc.

Comment: yes, database is declared and i am able to get the word from the database but not its id. there are two columns with Word and wordId..

Comment: @ryandlf: _id is required for ListView/Adapter not for the database. However, you need to query "select wordId as _id ..." if using a ListView with your own PK columnname.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that `wordid` is not `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` therefore it returns `0`. Check it at first.

Every row in table has it's own id with names `rowid`, `oid`, or `_rowid_`. Use it instead if you just need to distinguish rows. Or debug database in shell.

```
adb -e shell

cd /data/data/your.app.package.name/databases

sqlite3 database

.headers on

select * from words;
```

Above works on emulator and rooted devices

Comment: wordId is is the Colum and each word has got its id...how to get it

Comment: I understand but is wordId an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: But `PRIMARY KEY`? It's important because of uniqueness and autoincrement.